# Find the value X where the number has been "rounded to the nearest X"

Tags: javascript, math, rounding, precision

What is the simplest way to estimate the nearest rounding, where we know the rounding is always e.g. 100, 10, 1, 0.1 etc. We don't necessarily know the original number.

```
8        => 1         // we have rounded to the nearest *one*
88       => 1
80       => 10        // we have rounded to the nearest *ten* 
4530     => 10
4000     => 1000      // we have rounded to the nearest *thousand*
0.024    => 0.001
0.02     => 0.01
0.024332 => 0.000001
4000.7   => 0.1       // we have rounded to the nearest *tenth*
```

This might be useful when, given one number, we want to round all other numbers by the same quantity. Thanks.

I am seeking to determine for any number, if we assume that the number has been rounded, how can we estimate what that rounding amount is?

For instance, given the number 4000, we estimate the number we started with was rounded to the nearest thousand. But given 4000.7, we estimate that the rounding was to the nearest tenth.

Comment: JavaScript floating point numbers are inexact. You'll have to use some other numerical representation before this problem can be solved. (For example, the value 0.1 does not exist as an IEEE floating point value. You can get very close, but it won't be exactly 0.1.)

Comment: I don't get the logic of your "rounding"? Why would 8 or 88 round to 1 instead of 10 or 100? Why would 4530 round to 10 but 4000 round to 1000?

Comment: @derpirscher The goal is to find the value X where the number has been "rounded to the nearest X".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Raymond Chen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76055069/find-the-value-x-where-the-number-has-been-rounded-to-the-nearest-x/76055782#comment134133159_76055069) has got this right - you **cannot** do this in a mathematical fashion, because of issues with floating point representations. So, you need a string-based function.

For integers we can use a RegEx to count the number of trailing zeros *n*, and the rounding will be 10^n.

For non-integers, we need the number of numbers *n* after the decimal point, again something we can do with RegEx. The rounding will be the inverse of 10^n.

```js
function getRounding(n){
  
    const s = n.toString();
  
    if(Number.isInteger(n)){        
      return Math.pow(10, /0+$/.exec(s)?.[0].length ?? 0);      
    }
    else
    {     
      return 1/Math.pow(10, (/\.\d+/.exec(s)?.[0].length ?? 0) - 1);     
    }
  
}

console.log(getRounding(8))
console.log(getRounding(88))
console.log(getRounding(80))
console.log(getRounding(4530))
console.log(getRounding(4000))
console.log(getRounding(0.024))
console.log(getRounding(0.02))
console.log(getRounding(0.024332))
console.log(getRounding(4000.7))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly a bit scrappy, but the idea is basically to find where the first thing that isn't zero is from the right and return a number based on that.

```js
const get_last_non_zero_position = (num_str) => {
  let i = num_str.length - 1;
  
  for(; i >= 0; i--)
    if(num_str[i] !== '0')
      return i;
  
  return -1;
};

const get_rounding = (number) => {
  const [int_part, dec_part] = (number + '').split('.');
  
  if(dec_part?.length) {
    const dec_sig_digit = get_last_non_zero_position(dec_part);
    if(dec_sig_digit > -1)
      return '0.' + '0'.repeat(dec_sig_digit) + '1';
  }
  
  const int_sig_digit = get_last_non_zero_position(int_part);
  
  return '1' + '0'.repeat(int_part.length - int_sig_digit - 1);
};

const test_items = [
  8, 88, 80, 4530, 4000, 0.024, 0.02, 0.024332, 4000.7,
  0.1, 0.3, 0.2 + 0.1, new Decimal(0.2).plus(0.1)
];

console.log(test_items.map(
  (item) => [item, get_rounding(item)].join(': ')
));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/decimal.js/9.0.0/decimal.min.js"></script>
```